User Context in JWT when sending request to Jira API
I am making a Jira Plugin, and I am testing my plugin. On my Jira I have two projects Project1 and Project2 and as the owner of the Jira i have access to both, but a different user(my friend) only has access to Project2. When I upload the plugin on Jira I get all the data when the /installed endpoint is made and i create a JWT and everything works fine. But the issue is when we retrieve all the projects both me and my friend the other user get two projects returned. I want Jira to return to him only Project2 the project he is a part of. When i build my JWT i use this
  jwt_token = atlassian_jwt.encode_token(
      "GET",
      url=data.baseUrl.strip("/") + "/rest/api/3/project/search",
      clientKey=data.key,
      sharedSecret=data.sharedSecret
  )

I also tried adding my friends accountId as 'sub' in the JWT payload but it still returns two Projects.  Help would be really appreciated.

This happens because you're accessing the project as the add-on user and not the user in context. To perform a user context request, you should use the impersonation JWT token, which you should generate before accessing the endpoint you want to return. The explanation is here and always ensure you have the scope ACT_AS_USER to enable this to work
